# "Enter a valid date" error in django when I edit the form

Tags: python, django

I am facing a problem with date while editing a form.

model.py

```
class Promotions(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

forms.py

```
class PromotionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CHOICES = (('Active','Active'),('Inactive', 'Inactive'))
    WEBSITE = (("CMS","CMS"),("Tutor","Tutor"),("Offers","Offers"),
               ("Promotions","Promotions"),("Orders","Orders"))
    status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
    website = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=WEBSITE, widget=forms.SelectMultiple)
    start_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}))
    expire_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Promotions
        fields = ["name", "description", "status", "website", "start_date", "expire_date"]
```

template when i give input 
[image: the date format when i creating new record]

template when i am editing

[image: the date format when i am in editing page]

please help
Thank you.

Comment: what is the error? Having a `datetime` field value instead of a `date`? If you can, in your model change the `start_date` and `expiry_date` to `DateField`

Comment: Thank you, DateField worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The type of fields `expire_date` and `start_date` in the model does not match their type in the form.

The values get stored as DateTime instead of Date.

In your model change `start_date` and `expiry_date` to `DateField`

```
class Promotions(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    expire_date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: ahem... it's always embarassing to ask... please then flag my answer as 'accepted' or at the very least upvote it. Thank you. Peace.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have minimum reputation to flag you.